# Is it possible to handle SignalException: SIGHUP while running a rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, exception, rake

I have a background job in rails which does some processing and if that job (rake task) process is terminated due to this exception SignalException: SIGHUP, I want to send an email so we can restart the rake again.

Is it possible to rescue from this exception, though I process is anyway going to terminate but atleast if I can send email before it terminates.

Please help.

Sample code:

```
task :generate_best_bets_for_all_users do
  begin
    // do some processing
    // if something is wrong 
  rescue SignalException => e
    // OK? to rescue this exception?, is this possible? I want to send email here
  rescue StandardError => e
    // notify for other failures
  end
end
```

PS: this process is run a detached dyno on heroku like - heroku run:detached rake-name --app=app-name

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: Please see original post, I have updated that.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [`Signal.trap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Signal.html) to catch things:

```
Signal.trap('HUP') do
  send_panic_email!
end
```

Try not to do anything too strenuous when rescuing signals, there are limits on what you can do and you might get errors if you violate these constraints. I think the limits depend on the signal and your OS.

Comment: Code is like this:

Comment: Ignore previous comment, code is like this:
task :generate_best_bets_for_all_users do
  begin

end

Comment: Ignore my previous comments, I hit enter by mistake. I have update original question with sample code and place where I want to send panic email

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you may be better off using something like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/). Your `rake` task could spawn a job, and if the server gets killed, Sidekiq will automatically push the job back into the queue. If the job is something that needs to happen at regular intervals, you could use [Heroku scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to automatically trigger the task. It sounds like it's a long running job, so if that's the case, it's important that the scheduler trigger a separate background job, otherwise it might get [killed the next schedule interval](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#long-running-jobs).